# Why is my WPF aplication loading animation steel Freezing?

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I am developing a desktop application for managing a forest catalog. When starting the application, certain data must be displayed from a MySql database, which slows down the start of the application, so I want to show a dialog that shows an animated gif until the data is finished loading.
The problem is that the application freezes and the dialog is not shown until the data loading is finished. I've searched other posts but can't find the solution. I appreciate any help, thanks.

This is my MainWindow XAML:

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="ModernUINavigationApp1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
Title="Media Copy Manager" IsTitleVisible="True"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"


ContentSource="/gui/Pages/PHome.xaml" WindowState="Maximized">

<mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
    ( ...)
</mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
```

Here is my PHome.xaml page:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MCP.gui.Pages.PHome"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}" Margin="0 0 0 0" Name="_contentRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="_TAB" TabStripPlacement="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

This is my Home.cs code :

```
{
    public PHome()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += ContentLoaded;
    }
    private void ContentLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         Thread t = new Thread(() =>
         {
             Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
               (Action)(() =>
               {
                   new LoadingDialog().Show();
               }));
         });
         t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
         t.IsBackground = true;
         t.Start();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _TAB.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (Action)(() =>
                {
                    Populate_Tab(_TAB);
                }));
        });
    }
    private async void Populate_Tab(TabControl tabControl)
    {
        tabControl.Items.Clear();
        tabControl.ClipToBounds = true;

        List<categoria> ListaCategorias = await DBManager.CategoriasRepo.ListAsync;
        foreach (categoria categ in ListaCategorias)
        {
            TabItem tabitem = new TabItem();
            tabitem.Header = categ.categoria1;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);   //Do some long execution process
            tabControl.Items.Add(tabitem);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my LoadingDialog XAML:

```
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                  xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
                  mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="300"
                  Title="ModernDialog" Background="{x:Null}" Height="197.368">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>LOADING</TextBlock>
        <mui:ModernProgressRing IsActive="True" Name="_LoaderGif" Width="100" Height="100" Style="{StaticResource ThreeBounceProgressRingStyle}" Margin="47,43,68,65" />
    </StackPanel>
</mui:ModernDialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a better understanding of the methods you're using, specifically the ones you are using to try and move things onto other threads. Before I explain, keep these things in mind:

- The main, default thread in a WPF application can be called the UI thread. All the code for the rendering and layout of the application is processed on this thread. All the code you write is also processed on this thread unless you say otherwise.
- A thread runs one method at a time, so any any long-running method on the UI thread will prevent it from running the methods necessary to layout and render the application (i.e. it will "freeze").
- Changes to UI elements- the visual aspects of the application- must be done from the UI thread.

**The thing you don't seem to understand is [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke)**.

Just like `Task.Run` moves code execution onto a new thread, `Dispatcher.Invoke` moves code execution *back onto the UI thead*.

Let's take your method `ContentLoaded`. In your code, you attempt to use both the `Thread` and `Task` classes to move some of your code onto a separate thread. But all you do from those new threads is immediately call `Dispatcher.Invoke`, which executes code back on the UI thread. This actually makes your app *slower*, in theory, because it's wasting time making new threads and jumping between them for no reason.

What you need to do is take `Populate_Tab` and separate it into two (or more) different methods: one that effects the UI and one that doesn't.

Calls like `tabControl.Items.Clear` and `tabitem.Header = categ.categoria1` have to be done on the UI thread because they directly reference UI elements, but your long-running operations, like accessing your database, can and should be moved onto another thread.

The sequence shoud be:

- Show the loading icon.
- Start a long running operation on another thread. I would recommend using `Task` with `async` and `await`, as that is the current best practice.
- Get all the data you need and make any calculations on that other thread.
- Return the needed data back to the UI thread (using `await`) and update the UI as needed.
- Remove the loading icon.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the prompt reply. I found the solution thanks to your explanation, however it is worth clarifying that after obtaining the data when inserting it into the visual component I had to do it within a thread.
Thank you!!!

Comment: @RaiselCastellanosSantiago Okay. Well, if you feel my answer solved your problem, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).